# SQL Server: only group consecutive records when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table that contains a record for each ward stay within a hospital spell (note: a spell can include transfers to other hospitals). Spellno is the unique identifier of a spell.  I would like to aggregate consecutive ward stays within a spell to hospital level. The problem I have is that if a patient goes from hospital1 to hospital2 and back to hospital1 a `GROUP BY` 'Spellno' and 'Hospital' would combine the two hospital1 stays, which I don't want to do.

e.g. if this was my data:

```
Spellno   Hospital   WardCode   WardStart   WardEnd 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
123       hosp1      ward1      01/04/2015  03/04/2015
123       hosp1      ward4      03/04/2015  05/04/2015
123       hosp2      ward2      05/04/2015  07/04/2015
123       hosp1      ward3      07/04/2015  10/04/2015
123       hosp1      ward1      10/04/2015  12/04/2015
```

I want to aggregate on Spellno and Hospital to get:

```
Spellno   Hospital   WardStart   WardEnd 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
123       hosp1      01/04/2015  05/04/2015
123       hosp2      05/04/2015  07/04/2015
123       hosp1      07/04/2015  12/04/2015
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783315/combine-consecutive-date-ranges

Comment: @VladimirBaranov 2018 R2

Comment: If performance of the answer by @lad2025 suits you, use it. If not, and usually the "spell" doesn't last for too many days, consider using a table of numbers and treating this problem as [`gaps and islands`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subquery in `WHERE` clause to filter out overlapping dates ranges and second subquery in `SELECT` to get range end.

```
SELECT Spellno, Hospital,D.WardStart,
   (SELECT Min(E.WardEnd)
    FROM #tab E
    WHERE E.WardEnd >= D.WardEnd
      AND E.Spellno = D.Spellno
      AND E.Hospital = D.Hospital
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM #tab E2
                      WHERE E.WardStart < E2.WardStart
                        AND E.WardEnd >= E2.WardStart
                        AND D.Spellno = E2.Spellno
                        AND D.Hospital = E2.Hospital)
  ) AS WardEnd
FROM #tab D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #tab D2
                  WHERE D.WardStart <= D2.WardEnd
                    AND D.WardEnd > D2.WardEnd
                    AND D.Spellno = D2.Spellno
                    AND D.Hospital = D2.Hospital)
```

*Warning:*

This query performance may not be the best but it would do the work.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380940)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Spellno ║ Hospital ║      WardStart      ║       WardEnd       ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║     123 ║ hosp1    ║ 2015-04-01 00:00:00 ║ 2015-04-05 00:00:00 ║
║     123 ║ hosp2    ║ 2015-04-05 00:00:00 ║ 2015-04-07 00:00:00 ║
║     123 ║ hosp1    ║ 2015-04-07 00:00:00 ║ 2015-04-12 00:00:00 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly (takes 13 seconds on my 440,000 record table). Only thing I don't understand is how the subquery in the SELECT works.

Comment: @MarkB The subquery in WHERE will get you correct WardStart and eliminate overlapping records. The subquery in SELECT will get the last `WardEnd` to enclose the time period. You can play with it `SELECT Spellno, Hospital,D.WardStart, D.WardEnd`. Keep in mind that both queries are correlated to main query

Comment: I get that, I'm just trying to unpick it so I understand how it works. I'll get there. Also, just realised that this falls over when the last ward stay has a NULL end date, i.e. the patient is still in hospital. I will post the answer when I have it.

Comment: @MarkB Now you are changing the rules of game. `NULL` in WardEnd wasn't in original question. For future add this to your question because it is very important.

Comment: Yes, this was an oversight on my part. Could I get round it by enclosing each WardEnd in an ISNULL e.g. ISNULL(E.WardEnd, 2099-01-01') >= E2.WardStart?

Comment: @MarkB Yes I was thinking about adding ISNULL too. But I see you've got it already. Anyway please for future be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the `(WardStart, WardEnd)` date ranges are strictly consecutive with no overlapping. For simplicity's sake, I'm also assuming that consecutive ranges don't exceed the [max recursion default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650045/the-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted-before-statement-completion).

This can be solved using recursive SQL:

```
WITH 
  data AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      VALUES (123, 'hosp1', 'ward1', CAST('2015-04-01' AS DATE), CAST('2015-04-03' AS DATE)),
             (123, 'hosp1', 'ward4', CAST('2015-04-03' AS DATE), CAST('2015-04-05' AS DATE)),
             (123, 'hosp2', 'ward2', CAST('2015-04-05' AS DATE), CAST('2015-04-07' AS DATE)),
             (123, 'hosp1', 'ward3', CAST('2015-04-07' AS DATE), CAST('2015-04-10' AS DATE)),
             (123, 'hosp1', 'ward1', CAST('2015-04-10' AS DATE), CAST('2015-04-12' AS DATE))
    ) AS t(Spellno, Hospital, WardCode, WardStart, WardEnd)
  ),
  consecutive(Spellno, Hospital, WardStart, WardEnd) AS (
    SELECT Spellno, Hospital, WardStart, WardEnd
    FROM data AS d1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM data AS d2
      WHERE d1.Spellno = d2.Spellno
      AND d1.Hospital = d2.Hospital
      AND d1.WardStart = d2.WardEnd
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Spellno, c.Hospital, c.WardStart, d.WardEnd
    FROM consecutive AS c
    JOIN data AS d
    ON c.Spellno = d.Spellno
    AND c.Hospital = d.Hospital
    AND c.WardEnd = d.WardStart
  )
SELECT Spellno, Hospital, WardStart, MAX(WardEnd)
FROM consecutive
GROUP BY Spellno, Hospital, WardStart
ORDER BY Spellno, WardStart
```

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380901/consecutive-date-ranges)

#### Explanation

The first subquery in the recursive CTE `consecutive` initialises the recursion to start with all rows for which there isn't any "previous row" for the same `(Spellno, Hospital)`. This produces:

```
Spellno  Hospital  WardStart   WardEnd
-----------------------------------------
123      hosp1     2015-04-01  2015-04-03
123      hosp2     2015-04-05  2015-04-07
123      hosp1     2015-04-07  2015-04-10
```

The recursion then produces a new row with the previous row's `WardStart` (which is always the same for consecutive rows) and the current `WardEnd`. This produces:

```
Spellno  Hospital  WardStart   WardEnd
-----------------------------------------
123      hosp1     2015-04-01  2015-04-03 <-- Unwanted, "intermediary" row
123      hosp1     2015-04-01  2015-04-05
123      hosp2     2015-04-05  2015-04-07
123      hosp1     2015-04-07  2015-04-10 <-- Unwanted, "intermediary" row
123      hosp1     2015-04-07  2015-04-12
```

Finally, in the outer query, we select only the maximum value of `WardEnd` for each consecutive series, producing the wanted result:

```
Spellno  Hospital  WardStart   WardEnd
-----------------------------------------
123      hosp1     2015-04-01  2015-04-05
123      hosp2     2015-04-05  2015-04-07
123      hosp1     2015-04-07  2015-04-12
```

Comment: This won't work see https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380956/consecutive-date-ranges for hosp2

Comment: Going to need to few minutes to get my head around this but many thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @LukasEder What if I change wards to `hosp2 ward1` like here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380957/consecutive-date-ranges this is analogic to `hosp1`

Comment: @lad2025: I made some assumptions about the data. I think your suggested data makes no sense in the context of the requirements. A patient / spellno cannot be in two different hospitals at the same time. If that assumption is wrong, then I'm happy to read the OP's updated question.

Comment: Changed different spellno, different hospital  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380958/consecutive-date-ranges, **still the same**.

Comment: @lad2025: Now we have a gap within the `spellno = 123` *and* overlapping date ranges for `(124, 'hosp2')` What is it you're trying to say here? :)

Comment: @LukasEder: your assumptions are correct. gaps or overlaps within a spellno would indicate corrupt data

Comment: @lad2025... Anyway, nonetheless, I find your solution more elegant for this specific question